# Zf 3 Introducing Services and the ServiceManager

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm getting error:

```
Fatal error: Class Blog\Factory\ListControllerFactory contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke) in /d0/home/kgendig/www/Zend/module/Blog/src/Blog/Factory/ListControllerFactory.php on line 28
```

I'm doing all with
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html

What i have to change, my zend_version(); is 2.6.0

```
<?php
// Filename: /module/Blog/src/Blog/Factory/ListControllerFactory.php
namespace Blog\Factory;

use Blog\Controller\ListController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ListControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $postService        = $realServiceLocator->get('Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface');

        return new ListController($postService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give your  `ListControllerFactory.php`, nobody can tell you what is wrong if you don't give your code. Then you are talking about ZF3 but give a link to ZF2.4 manual and have a 2.6 version. Work with ZF2 or ZF3 but don't miw parts that are not designed to work together...

Comment: ok i paste it into my first note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListControllerFactory` class implements the `FactoryInterface`. So you have to define all abstract functions of this interface in your class. Here, your `FactoryInterface` needs the `__invoke()` method (check how you call it), so you have to define it in your `ListControllerFactory`.

It seems you are mixing ZF2/3 components. In ZF3 `FactoryInterface` code ([see here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/master/src/FactoryInterface.php)), you have instructions for upgrading from V2 to V3:

> If upgrading from v2, take the following steps:
>
> - rename the method `createService()` to `__invoke()`, and:
> - rename the `$serviceLocator` argument to `$container`, and change the typehint to `Interop\Container\ContainerInterface`
> - add the `$requestedName` as a second argument
> - add the optional `array $options = null` argument as a final argument
> - create a `createService()` method as defined in this interface, and have it proxy to `__invoke()`.

This describe how to solve your problem, but maybe there are several similar issues in your code. Try not mixing ZF2.4 and ZF3 component. Don't use `dev-master` in your `composer.json`. I suggest you to use only ZF2 component and ZF2 tutorial, or, if you want to learn ZF3, only ZF3 components and the ZF3 tutorial.

Comment: Tank You. I start from the begining instaling ZF 2.4 and its works.